# PHP check if some keys or values are in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, validation, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array structure where I want to check if a key/value is present somewhere in the array. But I want to make the test in such a way that I make a an almost mirrored validation array.

Lets say I have a multidimensional array. This is the data I want to validate.

```
Array
(
[key1] => Array
    (
        [subkey1] => value
        [subkey2] => value
    )

[key2] => Array
    (
        [subkey3] => Array
            (
                [key1] => value
                [key2] => value
                [key3] => value
                [key4] => value
                [key5] => value
                [key6] => value
            )
    )
);
```

And this is the array of my keys and values that need to be present in the first array.

```
Array
(
[key1] => Array
    (
        [subkey2] => value
    )

[key2] => Array
    (
        [subkey3] => Array
            (
                [key5] => value
                [key6] => value
            )
    )
);
```

I cant compare the two arrays because they will never be the same. But I need to run through the data array somehow and validate up against the validation array. Both the key and value need to be at the right place and the key need the same name and the value should be the same as well. I'm just not sure how to make a decent check. Can I make some recursive check? Since some of the keys can be a value or another array it needs to check for this as well... that's why I'm thinking recursive but I'm not sure how to make that.

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Should "subkey" arrays be considered equal if the keys match or should also all values be matched?

Comment: Well is all about the values. But since you need to validate a value the array key needs to be equal as well otherwise the value wont be found. Did that make sence?

Comment: I think you need to walk through the array with an recoursive function to check each key and value. I think there is no simpler way.

Comment: At least make an example that works; you can't have duplicate keys in arrays declararations.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing @steven... any idea how I would go at it?

Comment: Sorry @Jack that should be fixed now.

Comment: I found this recusive funcktion [http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=10200] - it shows how I can get all the key and values. This is great but I still need to verify the structure of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this to recursively determine whether all required keys are present:

```
function has_recursive($data, $required)
{
    foreach ($required as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($data[$key])/* && $data[$key] === $value */) {
            return false;
        }
        if (is_array($data[$key]) && false === has_recursive($data[$key], $value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

has_recursive($data, $required); // false or true
```

Comment: Brilliant @Jack - looks very promising. Ill give it a spin.

Comment: Great @Jack I have now implemented the solution and added check on values as well. Its working great... I'm not sure how to add the check I have made to your answer. I'm not that familiar with stackoverflow's way of adding such additions.

Comment: Yes @Jack pretty much. Just if anyone should find this thread but you pretty much summed it up :) You should have received an up vote now. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it so maybe this doesn't work (if so and this would be no help I will remove the answer).

First method is to check each key-value pairs recursively and then find what matches.

The second option can be that you recursively create flat key - value arrays using `array_values()` and `array_keys()`. I mean from something like

```
array(
  'subkey1' = array(
     'key1' = value1,
     'key2' = value2),
  'subkey2' = value3
)
```

You iteratively and recursive do

```
array(
  'key1' = value1,
  'key2' = value2,
  'subkey2' = value3
)
```

If you do this with both arrays being compared, you can find the matching key-value pairs using `array_intersect_assoc()`.

This would however won't work if for example `'key1' == 'subkey2'`.

Comment: Good idea @Voitcus My only issue with this is if two subarrays contains the same key with different values. I guess it would override one of the keys. I don't think that's the current case, that the data contains same keys but in order to future proof the code i'm afraid of doing so :S

Comment: Yes, there was assumption that there are no duplicate keys in subarrays. In your case it was my first proposal, but marked only and detailed by @Jack. You should then test/improve and probably accept his answer, because only recursive searching seems to be non-sensitive.