# Check if key exists in array from function result - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function which checks the children on a tree given the parent ID:

```
function categoryChild($id) {

    $mysqli = dbConnect();

    $query = "select folders_id, childof from folders where childof = $id";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $children = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $children[$row['folders_id']] = categoryChild($row['folders_id']);
        }
    }

    return $children;
}
```

If I use: `print_r(categoryChild($folder_id));` I get e.g. the following:

```
Array ( [21] => Array ( [22] => Array ( ) ) [24] => Array ( [25] => Array ( ) ) )
```

I want to be able to check simply check against the numbers in the array(s)...I've tried:

```
if(in_array ("25", categoryChild($folder_id))){
    echo 'yeah';
};
```

But it simply does nothing.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You're injecting SQL into your code making it **insecure**. Use prepared statements and bound variables instead.

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks but I'll deal with that later, I will be using PDO probably when I get it all to work as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to check the `key` no the `value`

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) you are checking if the `value` exist

You have to use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) in order to check the `key`

```
if (array_key_exists(25, categoryChild($folder_id))) {
    echo 'yeah';
 }
```

To find a key in nested array you can use this:

```
 $keySearch=25;
 $array=categoryChild($folder_id);

foreach ($array as $array_data) {
    if (array_key_exists($keySearch, $array_data)) {
     echo 'yeah';
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

25 is INT no a string

[A useful link how to prevent SQL Injections in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

**UPDATE**

if your array is something like this

```
$array = array(
    21 => '',
    24 => array(
        22 => '',
        25 => ''
    )
);

$keySearch = 21;

if (count($array) == count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) {
//  single array
  if (array_key_exists($keySearch, $array)) {
    $result = 'yeah1';
  }else{
    $result = 'no';
  }
} else {
//  nested array;
  foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($keySearch, $array)) {
      $result = 'yeah2';
    }else{
      $result='no';
    }
  }
}

echo $result;//output yeah2
```

Comment: as his output (print_r) the first example with array_key_exists should be working.

Comment: Yes...another option -:)

Comment: Still not working properly - in this it only sees 22 & 25 as keys - Array ( [21] => Array ( ) [24] => Array ( [22] => Array ( ) [25] => Array ( ) ) )

Comment: @DarrenSweeney post your array to test, the array what you posted is incorrectly [try this](http://phpoverflow.eu01.aws.af.cm/print_r/)

Comment: @EmilioGort it shows "$object = NULL;" but it is exactly what print_r(categoryChild($folder_id)) gives me as shown in OP.

Comment: @EmilioGort Thanks, but the nesting could be 3, 5 or even 10 deep... can it not recurse somehow until its at the end of the tree?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808220/php-check-if-some-keys-or-values-are-in-a-multidimensional-array?rq=1#answer-16809626

Answer (score 1):

You can use **array_key_exists()** or a simple **isset**.

```
if(isset($ARR[$key]))
     echo "yep!";
```

Comment: When the array key exists but the value is null, isset will return false and array_key_exists will return true.

Comment: True! But may be useful if the user know that his values wont be null.